# What is "Oracle Access"?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I'm reading a paper for school and I have come across a passage that I don't understand. It says "If we allow the query to access the entries of the array through an oracle, it is possible to obtain a data structure of sublinear size".

Searching for information on what Oracle Access is has given me nothing but stuff about Oracle Databases, which is obviously not what I'm looking for. I can't really wrap my head around what this means.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think it's related to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine i.e. an oracle auto-magically knows how to do certain things

Comment: This is off-topic for SO but on-topic for cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the author is using fancy words to say that the data structure has sub-linear size *if you ignore the size of the array*. This might be useful to know if the array is shared among many instances of the structure. Oracles are often used to express a model of computation that extends another model of computation in some specific way.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, an oracle is just an imaginary tool used by the author to explain something else. The author doesn't want to go into how to access the data because it isn't extremely relevant, so he just says "an oracle". It's not an actual technology. [Oracle Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine)

Comment: The only issue I have with this is that it makes oracle machines sound like hand waving used to paper over a lack of rigor. That's not the case. Oracle machines are perfectly precise and valid models of computation, and useful to boot. They don't allow the author to skim over anything, they allow *abstracting* over how the details of the oracle, i.e., they give results that are true for any implementation of the oracle.

Comment: It's also probably not about an oracle machine in the narrow sense of the word, though I can't tell from the limited context here.